# How to install oldest version of chrome

Tags: dpkg, google-chrome

i have some tests in gitlab pipeline and now they dont work
This is my code in teh file `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
build:
  before_script:
    - sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
    - sudo apt-get update
    - wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14.0.2/205943a0976c4ed48cb16f1043c5c647/12/GPL/openjdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - tar xvf openjdk-14.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
    - sudo mv jdk-14.0.2 /usr/lib/jvm
    - sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/javac" 3
    - sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/java" 3
    - sudo update-alternatives --set "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/javac"
    - sudo update-alternatives --set "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/java"
    - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - apt --fix-broken install
```

Listing of error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (111.0.5563.146-1) over (61.0.3163.91-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2); however:
  Version of libgbm1:amd64 on system is 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libu2f-udev; however:
  Package libu2f-udev is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libvulkan1; however:
  Package libvulkan1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: The version of Chrome you are trying to install needs some old versions of other modules that you do not have. If you want to run this older Chrome you will need to make a docker container and install a version of Ubuntu that has those modules and runs that old version of Chrome. You can not change the version of the modules in question it will mess up other apps and maybe the whole system.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: You didn't provide OS/release details; so I did a quick scan of your packages, and the only match is EOSS `mime-support | 3.59ubuntu1   | xenial          | source, all` (with a second I scanned also matching only off-topic *xenial*; `menu | 2.1.47ubuntu1         | xenial/universe         | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x`)